Which verb tense best completes this sentence according to Standard English conventions?

The Many Farms Chapter is one of the 110 chapters of the Navajo Nation (Naabeehó Bináhásdzó). The chapter, known as Dá’ák’eh Halání in the Navajo language (Diné bizaad), was the subject of a profile _____ in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.

A) appeared
B) has appeared
C) appears
D) appearing


My Answer: I believe the correct answer is D) appearing because it seems to work as a participle phrase modifying “profile.” In this context, “appearing” functions like a descriptor or continuation of the sentence rather than a finite verb. To me, it aligns with the style and flow of the sentence, though I want to ensure this interpretation is consistent with Standard English grammar conventions.
On the other hand, I also assume that the full sentence might read as follows:

The chapter was the subject of a profile that appeared in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.

Question: Is “appearing” a correct and valid choice here, and if not, why?

Certainly your possibilities are far more restricted when that/which is absent than when it is present, aren't they?
